How does A trust if X is a physical fingerprint of B?
$B$ stated to $A$ that $X$ is his physical fingerprint.
Problem:



How to make $A$ trust that the $X$ is really a physical fingerprint of $B$?




How to prevent $B$ from creating multiple identities, let assume he has only one physical finger?



What is the best protocol (rule of set that has been defined and agreed between two parties) to solve these problems without any third party?
I think there must be rigorous and layered protocol (analogous to the OSI layer) to define them so it can be fair for both parties. First, I need to define the axiom:

A physical fingerprint is the lifetime hash.

My main concern is about the physical layer, where the data source needs to be validated and verified.
Here, if multiple vendors of hardware scanners are using different technologies, implementations, and standards, does it produce different results of raw fingerprints when they are digitized into binary data? Even though in reality, physical fingerprints never change. Moreover, vendor means third party.
So does it mean a pattern recognition algorithm that has been agreed upon by both parties must be involved? Maybe AI that has a binary classifier task (a fingerprint input or not) must be involved? Then after $X$ classified as valid fingerprint input and reported to $A$, $X$ is performing digital hash.
But then the produced has will be dynamic values even though verified by an AI classifier whenever $B$ perform validation, which makes $B$ possible to create multiple identities, thus it's hard to answer the second problem.

If multiple vendors of hardware scanners are using different technologies, implementations, and standards, does it produce different results of raw fingerprints when they are digitized into binary data? Yes. And worse: unless they communicate, multiple hardware fingerprint scanners (from the same vendor) won't produce the same output for a given finger. That's not the only issue with fingerprint scanners: it's feasible to clone a fingerprint. I think this is an IT security question, more appropriate on Security-SE
